# IEnumerable<T> having the same type as the return value of delegate

Tags: c#

I have a function declared this way:

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> s1,
                                                        IEnumerable<T> s2,
                                                        Func<T, T> funcDel)
    { ... }
```

I need to use this function as parameter:

```
            Func<char, bool> sampleF = (ch) => { //stuff }
```

But the IDE returns an error because the type argument cannot be inferred. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How can I set my method to return the same type of the delegate?

Comment: You have declared `Func<T, T>`. Both `T` are the same `T`. `<char, bool>` are two different `T`. If you wanted them different, you needed `IEnumerable<T1, T2> MyMethod<T1, T2>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `funcDel` as `Func<T, T>`. Both `T` are the same. However, `sampleF` is of type `Func<char, bool>`. `<char, bool>` are two different `T`.

If you wanted them different, you needed `IEnumerable<T2> MyMethod<T1, T2>` with `funcDel` of type `Func<T1,T2>`

Comment: More like `IEnumerable<T2>`

Comment: What is `IEnumerable<T1, T2>`?